# jQuery: How Do I simulate Drag and Drop in Code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable

EDIT: Here's a link to show you my sample code: http://www.singingeels.com/jqtest/

I have a very simple page that references jquery-1.3.2.js, ui.core.js (latest version) and ui.draggable.js (also latest version).

I have a div that I can drag around very easily (using the mouse of course):

```
<div id="myDiv">hello</div>
```

and then in JavaScript:

```
$("#myDiv").draggable();
```

This is works perfectly. But, I need to be able to simulate a 'drag and drop' using code alone. **I have it mostly working, but the problem is that the events that are firing are the placeholder events**.

If you open "ui.core.js" and scroll to the bottom... you'll see this:

```
// These are placeholder methods, to be overriden by extending plugin
_mouseStart: function(event) { },
_mouseDrag: function(event) { },
_mouseStop: function(event) { },
_mouseCapture: function(event) { return true; }
```

Why aren't the events being extended properly in my simulation, but when you click down with the mouse, they are? - Any ideas on how to force the _mouseDrag: property to obey the overriding extension in "ui.draggable.js"?

Solving this would be huge - and I plan to show the major benefits later.

Thanks,
-Timothy

EDIT: Here's a link to show you my sample code: http://www.singingeels.com/jqtest/

EDIT 2: Click that link above and view-source... you'll see what I'm trying to do. Here's a snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myDiv = $("#myDiv");

    myDiv.draggable();

    // This will set enough properties to simulate valid mouse options.
    $.ui.mouse.options = $.ui.mouse.defaults;

    var divOffset = myDiv.offset();

    // This will simulate clicking down on the div - works mostly.
    $.ui.mouse._mouseDown({
        target: myDiv,
        pageX: divOffset.left,
        pageY: divOffset.top,
        which: 1,

        preventDefault: function() { }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you show us your code? Tell us what is not working and how you expect it to work.

Comment: Why aren't you just using all of JQueryUI as one file?

Comment: I'll try to put up a code sample... the reason for having the UI stuff separated is for debugging only.

Comment: If you click on the sample link above and do a view-source, you'll see what I mean by "code alone".

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? I'm attempting mousedown() and loop of mousemove(eventData) and mouseup(), but isn't working so much.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's a [question in the JQuery forum about it](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/fire-events-to-simulate-drag-n-drop). It's not resolved at the time of writing, but may have more information in the future.

---

**EDIT:** It was answered on the forum:

> I recommend you use the simulate plugin which is what jQuery UI uses for unit testing drag and drop:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/external/jquery-simulate/jquery.simulate.js

> You can see examples of use by looking at the unit tests

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/tests/unit/draggable/core.js

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/tests/unit/draggable/events.js

Thanks to rdworth for that.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution that works pretty well. I have the drop event call a function called `onDragAndDrop()`. That function takes two arguments, the `draggable` jQuery object and the `droppable` jQuery object.

```js
$('.my-drop-target').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        onDragAndDrop(ui.draggable, $(event.target));
    }
});
```

In my tests, I have a function that calls onDragAndDrop directly, but makes sure that a user with a mouse could have performed that action.

```js
    var simulateDragAndDrop = function(draggable, droppable) {
        if (!draggable.data('uiDraggable')) {
            throw new Error('Tried to drag and drop but the source element is not draggable!');
        }
        if (!droppable.data('uiDroppable')) {
            throw new Error('Tried to drag and drop but the target element is not droppable!');
        }
        onDragAndDrop(draggable, droppable);
    }
```

I've found it to be a nice, easy-to-use solution for unit tests. I'll probably end up using it for a keyboard-accessible fallback as well.

Comment: This is a custom function of `onDragAndDrop`?