# Easy way to "simulate" a drag-and-drop using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, simulation, droppable

I have a web page that allows the user to drag elements into a droppable div. I'm using JQuery UI Draggable and Droppable. I would like to add the functionality that if you double-click on one of the draggable elements, it "simulates" a drag-and-drop of that element - i.e. it drags the element across the screen and drops it on the droppable div. This way the user has the option to drag and drop, or simply to double click. Is there any way to implement this easily? (If it's too much of a hassle I will probably just code the double click to execute the code and then pop up an alert that it was done.)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to develop something to you without piece of code, but here is an idea:

You could use [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function fired by your element "doubleclick" event to move your draggable elemtent to the drop zone.

Calculate target position should not be hard using [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) functionalities.

Then, use the .animate() callback to execute the drop action.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question here: [jQuery: How Do I simulate Drag and Drop in Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166246/jquery-how-do-i-simulate-drag-and-drop-in-code)
and I solved using the solution proposed by Patrick McElhaney:

```
    $(".mainpanel").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            onDragAndDrop($(ui.draggable), $(event.target));
        }
    });

    button.dblclick(function () {
        onDragAndDrop($(this), $(".mainpanel"));
    });

    function onDragAndDrop(dragged, droppable) {
        // ...
    }
```